# AJAX Form Submit v/s Standard Form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest, google-search-appliance

I am trying to implement GSA(Google Search Appliance) in my app. I want to use the REST(JSON) call that the GSA provides. The point for this question is that, the GSA needs a POST request in order to return the JSON response.

Now when I made a new dummy HTML page with a form and make a POST request with parameters I get a successful response(JSON)

But, when I try using the `$.post(...)` method to send a POST request to the URL I am not getting the actual response, but some error page.

I just wanted to know is there a difference between a standard submit and an ajax form submit. If yes, is there any workaround for this situation.

Please Help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Don't forget to `serialize()` your form!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit the form through ajax but in the conventional way, You should have a look at [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) . Just make your submit button to type button and on click submit your form thorugh .ajaxSubmit(). I think this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

GSA search protocol is based on HTTP GET. All search parameters need to be passed in via query string. Also, out of box, GSA only returns either HTML or XML results. You could apply an xslt that transforms xml to JSON -- but I'm yet to find one that works really well (i.e., I've found a couple but they don't return valid JSON in all instances).